# Command to see msg data in Tibco EMS

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems

we published some msgs to queue in EMS server.

we want see MSG data(content) for each msg

can you please let me know steps how to do.

Thanks
venkateshwar

Answer (score 0):

You can use a java class to listen on the specified topic or queue .. I think you can find a sample code under the EMS installation .. there are a sample to send an XML file as a message .. using this command

```
call C:\tibco\ems\samples\java\setup
REM: Sending Queue Message 
java -cp %CLASSPATH%;C:\tibco\ems\samples\java tibjmsQueueSender -queue %COMPUTERNAME%.PurchaseOrder.Batch "C:\BWEDU\BatchOrder\BatchOrder01.xml"
```

I hope this could help!